# .netcore unit testing not running properly

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit.net

I have created some unit tests for a simple c#/dotnet-core console application.
I have created the reference on the testing project but for some reason the "dotnet test" cmd is still reporting the following error:

> UnitTest1.cs(12,25): error CS0103: The name 'LinkChecker' does not
>   exist in the current context
>   [/Users/med.bensalem/Desktop/dotnet-projects/checklinksTests/checklinksTests.csproj]
>   UnitTest1.cs(19,25): error CS0103: The name 'LinkChecker' does not
>   exist in the current context
>   [/Users/med.bensalem/Desktop/dotnet-projects/checklinksTests/checklinksTests.csproj]

Project structure:

```
.
├── checklinksTests
│   ├── UnitTest1.cs
│   ├── checklinksTests.csproj
└── checklinksconsole
    └── code
        ├── LinkChecker.cs
        ├── Program.cs
        └── checklinksconsole.csproj
```

Please find below the code I project source code:

**Main application - checklinksconsole:**

*checklinksconsole.csproj - file:*

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore" Version="1.5.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

*Program.cs - file:*

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace checklinksconsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var site = "https://www.google.com";
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var body = client.GetStringAsync(site);
            Console.WriteLine(body.Result);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Links:");
            var links = LinkChecker.GetLinks(body.Result);
            links.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }
}
```

*LinkChecker.cs - file:*

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace checklinksconsole
{
    public class LinkChecker
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> GetLinks(string page)
        {
            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(page);
            var links = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
                .Select(n => n.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty))
                .Where(l => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
                .Where(l => l.StartsWith("http"));
            return links;
        }
    }
}
```

**Unit testing - checklinksTests:**

*checklinksTests.csproj - file:*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\checklinksconsole\code\checklinksconsole.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

*UnitTest1.cs - file:*

```
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace checklinksTests
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void WithoutHTTPAtTheStartOfTheLink_NoLinks()
        {
            var links = LinkChecker.GetLinks("<a href=\"google.com\" />");
            Assert.Equal(links.Count(),0);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void WithHTTPAtTheStartOfTheLink_LinkParses()
        {
            var links = LinkChecker.GetLinks("<a href=\"http://google.com\" />");
            Assert.Equal(links.Count(),1);
            Assert.Equal(links.First(), "google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea on what is wring with my code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re missing a `using checklinksconsole;` directive at the top of your test class to bring the `LinkChecker` class into scope.